# what are the most frequently used 3rd party django database backends for MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, django, azure

Currently I'm using django-pyodbc-azure with django 1.11. But it seems slower than other. Is there any other library that performs faster than this? Can anyone suggests me some other libraries to check the query performances?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone suggests me some other libraries to check the query
>   performances?

Besides `django-pyodbc-azure`, you can use [`django-mssql`](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

The default database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'my_database',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'dbserver\\ss2012',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}
```

Or you could use [django-pyodbc](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc#django-pyodbc) package which is basis of django-pyodbc-azure.

> Is there any other library that performs faster than this?

Query data performance is affected by a number of factors, such as the network is slow, query statements are not optimized, low memory, index and so on. You can optimize it in a number of ways.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Sorry, looking through the documentation I came to know that django-mssql and django-pyodbc has no support for django 1.11 and later versions.

Comment: @xalien Well then I suggest you using django-pyodbc-azure for now time until the other packages support django 1.11.Thx

Comment: @xalien If you adopt the answer, you could mark it for others' reference on the forum.Thx.